# javascript regex, word not followed and not preceded by specific char

Tags: javascript, regex

I guess I'm not very good at regular expressions, so here is my problem (I'm sure it's easy to solve, but somehow I can't seem to find how )

```
var word = "aaa";
text = text.replace( new RegExp(word, "g"),
                     "<span style='background-color: yellow'>"+word+"</span>");
```

this is working in most cases.

What I want to do is for the regex ONLY TO WORK when word is not followed by the char **/** and not preceded with char **"**.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're going to want to use a negative look-ahead.

Regex: `'[^"]' + word + '(?!/)'`

Edit: While it doesn't matter as it appears you already found your answer by avoiding look-behinds, Rohit noticed something I didn't. You're going to need to capture the [^\"] and include it in the replace so that it does not get discarded.
This wasn't necessary for the look-head since look-arounds by definition aren't included in captures.

Comment: thanks alot. so if i also want it to not to be preceded by char " i should make it "(?!\")" + word + "(?!\/)" ?

Comment: If you want to make sure " does not precede word, you need to use a negative look-behind. So you would need `(?<!\") + word + (?!\/)`. Check out this link, it's where I learned how to use these: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Javascript does not supprt look-behinds.

Comment: new RegExp("(?<!\")"+word+"(?!\/)", "g") says invalid quantifier when i add the look behind.

Comment: @RohitJain Ah well then since negative look-behinds don't work, you can just use a negated character class. `[^\"] + word + (?!\/)`. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: indeed it can't look behind. i solved it by checking two characters, as it should not find it if it also has a number after the slash, so no need to look behind. solution: word+"(?!\/[0-9])", "gi". the preceding [^\"] that you posted breaks things.

Comment: `'[^"]' + word + '(?!/)'` is enough.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex: -

```
'([^"])' + word + '(?!/)'
```

and replace it with - `"$1g"`

Note that Javascript does not support look-behinds. So, you need to capture the previous character and ensure that it is not `"`, using negated character class.

See demo at http://fiddle.re/zdjt

Comment: This fails if the match is at beginning or end of line. Perhaps the question could mention whether this matters.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the question can be interpreted as

1. *match word not preceded **AND** not followed* (`"aaa` and `aaa/` should match, same as `"aaa/`) and as
2. *match word not preceded **OR** not followed* with some char(s) (`"aaa`, `aaa/` should not match, while `"aaa/` should).

If you are using a JavaScript environment that *supports* [ECMAScript 2018](https://262.ecma-international.org/9.0/), you can use a lookbehind solution:

```js
const word = 'aaa',                     // Word to find
    left = '"',                         // Left-hand negative marker
    right = '/',                        // Right-hand negative marker
    text = 'aaa aaa/ "aaa "aaa/ aaaaa'; // Test string

// Relace any 'word' that does not start with " OR does not end with /
var regex = new RegExp(String.raw`\b(?<!${left})${word}\b(?!${right})`, 'g')
console.log( text.replace(regex, "<span style='background-color: yellow'>$&</span>") );
// => <span style='background-color: yellow'>aaa</span> aaa/ "aaa "aaa/ aaaaa

// Replace any 'word' that does not start with " AND does not end with /
var regex = new RegExp(String.raw`\b${word}\b(?!(?<=${left}${word})${right})`, 'g')
console.log( text.replace(regex, "<span style='background-color: yellow'>$&</span>") );
// => <span style='background-color: yellow'>aaa</span> <span style='background-color: yellow'>aaa</span>/ "<span style='background-color: yellow'>aaa</span> "aaa/ aaaaa
```

If you are using a JavaScript environment that does not support [ECMAScript 2018](https://262.ecma-international.org/9.0/), you can use

```js
var word = 'aaa',                       // Word to find
    left = '"',                         // Left-hand negative marker
    right = '/',                        // Right-hand negative marker
    text = 'aaa aaa/ "aaa "aaa/ aaaaa'; // Test string

// Relace any 'word' that does not start with " OR does not end with /, one match expected
var regex = new RegExp("([^" + left + "\\w]|^)(" + word + ")\\b(?!" + right + ")", 'g')
console.log( text.replace(regex, "$1<span style='background-color: yellow'>$2</span>") );
// => <span style='background-color: yellow'>aaa</span> aaa/ "aaa "aaa/ aaaaa

// Same as above, but in case "left" is a sequence of chars, not a single char, or a longer pattern:
var regex = new RegExp("(" + left + ")?\\b(" + word + ")\\b(?!" + right + ")", 'g')
console.log( text.replace(regex, function(x,g,gg) { return g ? x : "<span style='background-color: yellow'>" + gg + "</span>";}) );
// => <span style='background-color: yellow'>aaa</span> aaa/ "aaa "aaa/ aaaaa

// Replace any 'word' that does not start with " AND does not end with /, three matches expected
var regex = new RegExp("(" + left + word + right + ")|\\b" + word + "\\b", 'g')
console.log( text.replace(regex, function(x, g) { return g || "<span style='background-color: yellow'>" + x + "</span>";}) );
// => <span style='background-color: yellow'>aaa</span> <span style='background-color: yellow'>aaa</span>/ "<span style='background-color: yellow'>aaa</span> "aaa/ aaaaa
```

Note:

- I use whole word matching here via `\b`, word boundary (and `\w` construct in the negated character class in one of the workarounds)
- If `right` and `left` chars/strings contain special regex metacharacters, mind to [escape them before using as part of a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493/3832970)
- Same escaping need might arise for the `word` variable, but in that case, if the `word` starts or/and ends with a special regex metacharacter, word boundaries (`\b`) will no longer work, you will need to use [adaptive/dynamic word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45145800/3832970).